# How to pass timeout by reference? Or a better way to implement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I had this code working previously, but I am not so sure now that I have separated my HTML controls from my jQueryUI Widget.

Currently, the timer starts correctly, but I lose my reference to _refreshTimeout after one tick. That is, after the first tick, unchecking my PlanViewRefreshCheckbox does not stop my timer from running.

I have two JavaScript files, PlanView.js and PlanViewCanvas.js.

PlanView.js looks something like this:

```
(function ($) {
    var _minZoom = -2.0;
    var _maxZoom = 2.0;
    var _stepZoom = (_maxZoom - _minZoom) / 100;
    var _refreshTimeout = null;
    var _refreshInterval = 60000; //One minute

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Initialize Refresh combo box.
        $('#PlanViewRefreshCheckbox').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                var planViewCanvas = $('#PlanViewCanvas');
                //Binding forces the scope to stay as 'this' instead of the domWindow (which calls setTimeout).
                _refreshTimeout = setTimeout(function(){planViewCanvas.PlanViewCanvas('refresh', _refreshInterval, _refreshTimeout)}.bind(planViewCanvas), _refreshInterval)
            }
            else {
                clearTimeout(_refreshTimeout);
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

and PlanViewCanvas.js houses a jQueryUI Widget:

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.PlanViewCanvas", {
        //other properties and methods not-relevant to problem declared here.
        refresh: function (refreshInterval, refreshTimeout) {
            var self = this;
            _stage.removeChildren();
            self.initialize();
            //Binding forces the scope to stay as 'this' instead of the domWindow (which calls setTimeout).
            refreshTimeout = setTimeout(function () { self.refresh(refreshInterval, refreshTimeout) }.bind(self), refreshInterval);
        },
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Does it seem like I am going about things incorrectly?

EDIT: I think the answer is probably to use setInterval and not setTimeout.

Comment: `(this).is(':checked')` would be hugely more efficient as simply `this.checked`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was very 'oh derp.'

```
    //Initialize Refresh combo box.
    $('#PlanViewRefreshCheckbox').click(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            _refreshTimeout = setInterval(function(){$('#PlanViewCanvas').PlanViewCanvas('refresh')}, _refreshInterval)
        }
        else {
            clearTimeout(_refreshTimeout);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you forgot the underscore

`refreshTimeout` should be `_refreshTimeout`

second, your variable needs to be global to be accessible in both files, so declare it outside of the function:

```
var _minZoom = -2.0;
var _maxZoom = 2.0;
var _stepZoom = (_maxZoom - _minZoom) / 100;
var _refreshTimeout = null;
var _refreshInterval = 60000; //One minute

(function ($) {
   ....
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: I didn't forget an underscore. I am passing the variable into the function (just failing at P-B-R). My widget does not have access to the scope in which _refreshTimeout resides. I was hoping to not pollute the global namespace by moving my variable outside of my induced scope as my widget doesn't 'care' about the timer -- only that it needs to respond by refreshing when told.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass values by reference. I see two options:

- pass an Object. If you have it referenced from two variables, you can access its properties in both scopes.
- split up you functionality in two functions, where it belongs: One masters the interval loop and triggers the refresh function, and the other does things to refresh. The `refreshTimeout` variable only belongs to the scope of the first one. point. You may add the interval function to you widget if it is often needed.

Comment: I opted to use the method setInterval instead of setTimeout as it was 100% suited to cope with the issue I had introduced.